# Force CakePHP 3.6 not to render JSON in AJAX call

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to respond to an ajax call but I get the message:
`Template file Events/json/index.ctp is missing.`
I guess it's because of the DataViews. I found a thousand solutions to change a normal request to ajax, but not the other way round.

So how can I tell Cake in `beforeRender()` not to use `Events/json/index.ctp` but `Events/index.ctp`?

Comment: this.viewBuilder().setTemplate or something setLayout or something like that (long time ago i used cake3) where `this` is controller.

Comment: setLayout ist probably working, but I don't know what to set in `setTemplate`. `getTemplate` is returning `null`.

Comment: You could also use requestHandlers https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html or extensions to specify if response (to any request if you would like) should be encoded as json or html markup.

Comment: I already tried using the request handler and unsetting '_serialize', but I don't know which configuration will change the path from /Events/json/index.ctp to /Events/index.ctp

Comment: its beacuse jsonview is used - thus template is resolved to "json group". _serialize is only indactor to which variables shhould be jsonized

Comment: That's what I figured cause JSONView is used automatically by CakePHP when doing an ajax call. But how is it possbile to change this?

Comment: It's not used for AJAX calls automatically, but for requests with `application/json` in the `Accepts` header, or the `.json` extension in the URL. Maybe you should modify your request instead?

Comment: It is actually a good idea to change the request. I think I will go with this solution. Thank you. But I think the framework should at least let me change the directory from which a template is loaded if I don't think that the convention is practical. And I don't want to create all the view files twice as HTML- and a JSON-version, because the JSON I can easily define in a Controller.

Comment: It does - by using view class.

Comment: But how and how conveniently? I don’t want to break out of certain auto rendering magic.

Comment: The convention isn't enforced on you, you can choose to not load / unload the request handler component (wich in the default sekeleton app is is loaded in `AppController`), and CakePHP will then straight away always render your regular `.ctp` file. With the component enabled you can also force rendering as a specific type if you want to, see **[`RequestHandlerComponent::renderAs()` and `respondAs()`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html#responding-to-requests)** (must be used in the `beforeRender` event).

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that I can deactivate the RequestHandler. I tried renderAs, but it was just adding e.g. 'text' to the path ending up with `/Events/text/json/index.ctp`. So I think I will just deactivate the RequestHandler.